# Open link in browser if there is keyword in datatable

Tags: javascript, .net, automation, uipath, rpa

There is a webpage where we have cases that we are working on.

Example:

[image: Page with an web page example]

I need a code for whenever there is a word like "cisco:AP" to open a link that is on the same DT line as the word in a new tab.

see another pic:

[image: what I want to achieve]

The link in the picture is dynamic it is always changing.

Comment: What sort of elements are returned on the website when you try like a click activity? Like are you able to get the Table Row number? If so, then Scrape the Table and obtain what row number that "Cisco" is present on.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the data table is also dynamic, so the raw nr. can change depending on how many tasks are there on the page. The only static thing is the Cisco text basically.

Comment: Is the application that's being used ServiceNow? Just looks familiar.   The table being dynamic shouldn't be an issue, try Scraping the Table to a DataTable and take the Index when Cisco is present.

Comment: Will try to do that. Yes, service now, unfortunately, I don't have admin access to DB so can not extract directly from there, so yes scarping will be one of the options.

Comment: Fair enough, there is an Activity Pack available for ServiceNow APIs which is quite good (or theres the usual REST API route) so might be worth getting in touch with the admin